# Does there exist a sequence of polynomials, interpolating a continuous function $f$ at a finite set of points converging uniformly to $f$?

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, weierstrass-approximation

I'm trying to determine whether the following is true:

Let $$f:[0,1] \xrightarrow[]{}\mathbb{R}$$ be continuous and $0\leq x_1<...<x_m\leq1$. Do there exist polynomials, $p_n$ such that $p_n(x_j)=f(x_j)$ for each $j=1,...,m$ and $p_n$ converges to $f$ on $[0,1]$.

So on the one hand we have the Weierstrass approximation theorem telling us that if we do not have our interpolating assumption then there is convergence. A thought I had was to consider $f(x)=|x-\frac{1}{2}|$ then we are looking for polynomials $\bar{p_n}$
such that $||\space(x-\frac{1}{2})\bar{p_n}-|x-\frac{1}{2}|\space||_\infty\xrightarrow[]{}0$ so in a sense we seek $\bar{p_n}$ converging uniformly to a discontinuous function which is not possible. But this is just an idea I have not managed to get to work.

So I would be interested to know if the statement is true and if my proposed counter example can be made to work.

Comment: Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2081349/42969

Comment: @MartinR In this answer, how do we know there exists such a $\textbf{polynomial}$,  $Q$ interpolating $f-P$ and remaining bounded by $\epsilon/2$?

Comment: $Q$ is the Lagrange interpolation polynomial for $f-P$ at the points $x_1, \ldots, x_n$. If you look at the formula for Lagrange interpolation then you can see that $|Q| < \epsilon/2$ if all $(f-P)(x_j)$ are sufficiently small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p_i(x)=\frac {\prod_{j \neq i} (x-x_j)} {\prod_{j \neq i}  (x_i-x_j)}$ and $P_n(x)=q_n(x)+\sum\limits_{i=1}^{m}p_i(x)[f(x_i)-q_n(x_i)]$ where $(q_n)$ is any sequence of polynomials converging uniformly to $f$. This sequence $(P_n)$ meets your requirements.